# How put a Lotus Notes in Dash?

Tags: unity, unity-dash, mail

I use Lotus Notes as the main program and would like have Lotus as  main email on Dash, not Evolution. How do I do this?

Ubuntu 11.04 (Unity)

Comment: I am not certain what you are asking.  Are you trying to get a launcher in the horizontal bar at the top or dock like bar to the left in Unity?

Comment: @Kory Wnuk: he wants to replace evolution with Lotus notes in the dash.

Answer (score 1):

Try to change the default program in the `Preferred applications`, you should find `Lotus notes` in the drop down list .

[image]

Answer (score 0):

If changing the default application doesn't work.

Then you could try first to remove `evolution` by typing `sudo apt-get remove evolution` command in the terminal, and then it may change automatically or you could change it manually in the `Preferred Applications` program.